# WxWidgets TextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Hello i have a simple question. I dont know how to check if the TextCtrl is empty. I have something like that

```
//Zmienne do ID

wxString wypisz_id=wxT("");
long int int_id;

//zmienne do Ilosc

wxString wypisz_ilosc=wxT("");
long int int_ilosc;

TextCtrl_dodaj_id->GetValue() .ToLong((&int_id));
wypisz_id << (int_id);

TextCtrl_dodaj_ilosc->GetValue() .ToLong((&int_ilosc));
wypisz_ilosc << (int_ilosc);
```

And i want to do if the `TextCtrl_dodaj_id` or `TextCtrl_dodaj_ilosc` will be empty my window will close or will be error. Someone can help me with tihs?

Comment: Use `TextCtrl_dodaj_ilosc->IsEmpty()`

Comment: @ReSS, the first stop for you shuold be an official documentation. And then if that doesn't work - ask away here or in the wx forum.